# Ajax POST to PHP is not detected

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this function to submit forms:

```
function submit_form(form) {
            $( form ).submit(function(e) {
                // Prevent form submission
                e.preventDefault();

                // Get the form instance
                var $form = $(e.target);

                // Use Ajax to submit form data
                $.ajax({
                    url : '/section' + $form.attr('action'),
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $form.serialize(),
                    mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData:false,
                    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        //if fails
                    }
                });
            });
        }
```

which sends a POST request to a PHP page.

in my PHP page i have

```
if($_POST)
    echo 'form posted';
    exit();
}
```

This processes fine, but "data" is not returning "form posted"

I am calling the function in the form tag:

```
<form id="edit_group" method="post" action="page.php" onsubmit="submit_form(\'#edit_group\');">
```

Further to the comments/convo, please see below the code that I am using:

My code looks like this:

```
<?php
if($_POST) {
    echo 'post';
    exit();
}
?>

<form id="edit_group" class="ajax_form" method="post" action="/page.php">

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.ajax_form').submit(function(e) {
    // Prevent form submission
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get the form instance
    var $form = $(e.target);

    // Use Ajax to submit form data
    $.ajax({
        url : '/section' + $form.attr('action'),
        type: "POST",
        data: $form.serialize(),

        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log("hi");
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //if fails
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there were a few issues worked through, through the comments to the question.

## Creating an event handler on form submit

The logic originally had an inline `onsubmit` for the form, with a method that was logically creating a submit event handler on the form.  However, for an event handler to process an event, it needs to exist before the event happens.  So this would result in the processing not happening the first time.  Taking the `onsubmit` off, and executing the method once to create the logical event binding would fix it to work the first time (and not multiple times) the form is submitted.

## contentType: false

By default, jQuery sets the ContentType to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is what normal form submits put on the request.  This tells the server to process the url query string and/or body in a particular manner.  In this case, it should expect it to be in a query string format and can auto parse the request into whatever construct your language expects.  For PHP, this would be the $_GET/$_POST/$_REQUEST variables.

By giving it false, you are telling jQuery to not put that header on there.  So without the header, PHP doesn't know that it needs to load $_GET or $_POST from the body, because it doesn't know how the data is structured.

Removing this option from the ajax request lets jQuery do the default, which lets PHP load the $_POST variable, which results in your conditional functioning as you expect it to.

Comment: perfect, thank you so much for your help! you've been a lifesaver :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Get rid of your function `submit_form(form)` and just leave the submit handler.

```
        $( form ).submit(function(e) {
            // Prevent form submission
            e.preventDefault();

            // Get the form instance
            var $form = $(e.target);

            // Use Ajax to submit form data
            $.ajax({
                url : '/section' + $form.attr('action'),
                type: "POST",
                data: $form.serialize(),
                mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false,
                success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    //if fails
                }
            });
        });
```

Also, change your html markup to this. (Remove the `onsumbit` attribute)

```
<form id="edit_group" method="post" action="page.php" >
```

Comment: I was just writing that :) Explain the `.submit()` handler works on the form where the submit button is clicked.

Comment: thanks for this, all makes sense. BUT, as per my comment above the content inside `if($_POST)` isn't showing

Comment: @charlie try `if(count($_POST))` or just get rid of the if

Comment: @bassxzero i cant get rid of the if because the form is on the same page below